# Where are the input values stored when using $host.ui.PromptForCredential?

Tags: powershell, security

In the following code, where does the system store the value for $Credential?

`$Credential= $host.ui.PromptForCredential("","Please Enter Your domain username, eg. user1@contoso.com","","")`

What happens to the value after the code has been executed?

Pardon the very basic questions... just want to be sure about any security implications on the script I'm making.  I was also hoping I could find the MSDN/TechNet article that specifically addresses this matter.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should use `Get-Credential` instead - it's easier and does the same job:

`$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Please Enter Your domain username, eg. user1@contoso.com"`

Both methods create a `PsCredential` object, a reference to which is stored in `$credential`.  The password is stored in memory as a `SecureString`, to help keep it safe, and not written to disk, registry, etc, unless you go out of your way to do so:

```
PS C:\> $credential

UserName                        Password
--------                        --------
domain\user System.Security.SecureString
```

So, it is safe from casual attempts to read.  However, it isn't entirely secure:

```
PS C:\> $credential.GetNetworkCredential() | Format-List *   

UserName       : user
Password       : Password123
SecurePassword : System.Security.SecureString
Domain         : domain
```

Comment: Wow! Nicely answered. So the values do get stored in memory, including the plain-text version of the password, instead of a sort of a one-way secure hash.  I did get the same output that you showed. Does that mean if the code is run inside a PS script, the values would still be in memory after the script is executed? And if so, what code should be added and executed to ensure the critical values are cleared and nuked? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The password is stored as a `SecureString` as part of the [PsCredential object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0), so normally, it is not easy to directly read.  However, at some point it must be used as a 'password', so it must be possible to convert back to plain text, which is what the call to `GetNetworkCredential()` does - actually, it returns a related object with the details 'decrypted'.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. =) Does that mean if the code is run inside a PS script, the values would still be in memory after the script is executed? And if so, what code should be added and executed to ensure the critical values are cleared and nuked?

Comment: Data can hang around in memory for a while after you're finished with it in your script since the .NET garbage collector isn't instant - it will eventually be cleaned up, and once you exit PowerShell, the memory for your session will be reclaimed by Windows.  I'm not aware of any PowerShell commands to blank specific pieces of memory, even if you could work out where the data was being stored.  To be honest, I don't think that level of paranoia is needed in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: You do have a point there.  Thanks for responding in [almost] real-time.  Really then, it won't be much of an issue if the bosses here would share the same sentiment, when I get to introduce the script that will make use of that line of code.  Anyway, I already took much of your time and I'm starting to turn this into a real online chat session... so, lastly, is there any specific MSDN/TechNet (and the likes) article that has all the meat on this? Thank you, boxdog.